# How can I solve this Ocaml dictionary problem?

Tags: ocaml

I have to write a function that has as parameters a dictionary and a character. The dictionary is string to string and you should look at it as a function. For example f("a")="b" in ("a", "b"). The function returns a max number for which f^number(character) is defined and an exception if f(character) cycles at infinity.

so if I have for eg this dictionary [("a", "b");("b", "c");("d", "e");("e", "f");("f", "e")]
my function appelead with this dictionary and charcater 'a' will give the result 2(a goes in b, b goes is c and it stops); for 'x' it will give 0 beacuse there's no such key; for 'b' the result will be 1(b goes in c and stops); for 'd' it will raise an exception(d goes in e, e goes in f, f goes in e and returns in e so infinite cycle); same exception for 'e' or 'f'

```
module MS = Map.Make(String);;
let d = MS.add "a" "b" (MS.add "b" "c" (MS.add "d" "e" (MS.add "e" "f" (MS.add "f" "e" MS.empty))));;
let f d c =
```

I just created the dictionary because I don't have any idea how could I implement this problem, but I think I need MS.Fold function for going through the dictionary.

Comment: Suggested for readability: `let d = MS.(empty |> add "f" "e" |> add "e" "f" |> add "d" "e" |> add "b" "c" |> add "b" "c")`

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of a fold is to "visit" all the elements of a structure, while accumulating some desired result. Your goal isn't to visit all the elements of your dictionary (which secretly is a graph). So a fold probably isn't what you want.

I'd say your main problem is in detecting cycles so you can raise an exception. To do this you need to track the places you've been. Then you raise the exception when you come to a place for the second time.

Otherwise this is a standard graph traversal problem, I'd say. You can solve it with a recursive function that visits nodes (i.e., looks up strings in the dictionary) until it gets a resolution. A resolution is a string that isn't in the dictionary, or a visit to a string that has already been visited.

**Update**

OK, I'll write some code that shows how to move through the dictionary. This function returns a string that is the concatenation of the first 10 strings it encounters. If it reaches a dead end before 10 it returns what it has seen so far. It uses your module `MS`.

```
 let what_i_saw dict str =
     let rec look sofar n s =
         if n <= 0 then
             sofar
         else
             match MS.find_opt s dict with
             | None -> sofar
             | Some s2 -> look (sofar ^ s2) (n - 1) s2
     in
     look str 9 str
```

Here's how it looks when you call the function:

```
# what_i_saw d "d";;
- : MS.key = "defefefefe"
# what_i_saw d "a";;
- : MS.key = "abc"
```

By the way, you say your function takes a character but your dictionary has keys that are strings. Strings and characters aren't the same thing in OCaml. I'm using strings everywhere in this example.

Comment: yeah, but that's like what I would have liked to see; a real piece of code that works(maybe not all but a slight idea), because theoretically, I understood what I have to do, but we didn't learn about graphs or trees so I have to use only the dictionary library, sets or maybe lists.(ty)

Comment: For what it's worth, if you can understand the assignment then I'd say you know enough about graphs to solve it. I.e., you see what it means to go from one word to the next and what it means to find a cycle.

Comment: I tried to update yr function on my problem but it keeps failing. I have hard times understanding all of yr code especially the match part as i am new to ocaml. I tried to add some conditions after in to stop at first cycle. I would apreciate very much if you could show me how to slove this.

Comment: With all due respect, you need to learn enough about OCaml to understand my code if you want to do this assignment. If you have specific questions you can ask them. If you show your code that failed people can help fix the problems. But asking SO to write your code for you usually doesn't work (as it shouldn't).

Comment: Thanks for yr indications. I managed to solve the problem a little bit differently from your approach. Here's the function I wrote and that works: module S = Set.Make(String);;
let depth dict s =
  let rec depth1 s dict num m=if(S.mem s m) then failwith "loop" else if (MS.mem s dict) then depth1 (MS.find s dict) dict (num+1) (S.add s m) else num
  in depth1 s dict 0 S.empty;;